# Jquery ajax post only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jquery script that posts a value:

```
// //Delete a product from the shopping cart
tpj('.remove').on('click', function() {
  // Stop form from submitting normally
  event.preventDefault();
  // Get some values from elements on the page:
  console.log('test');
  var $remove = tpj(this).attr('id');
  url = 'includes/shoppingcart.php';
  // Send the data using post
  var posting = tpj.post( url, { remove: $remove} );
  // Put the results in a div
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    var content = tpj( data );
    tpj( "#result" ).empty().append( content );
  });
});
```

This works the first time, but when I click a second time I redirect to my homepage, which makes sense since the anchor tag the `.remove` class is in has nothing in its href. However this means the `preventdefault()` is not working, the entire on click is not working.

Why is that? I googled and found out I should use `.on` instead of `.click` but this didn't change anything for me.

The following html line (which fires the jquery):

```
 <a href="" class="remove" id="'.$cartproduct['product'].'" title="Verwijder product">×</a>
```

is in my header.php and `shoppingcart.php`, when the ajax post is made and the result of `shoppingcart.php` is loaded in my shopping cart, the link stops working like it should.

What do I need to do?

Comment: Does `tpj( "#result" ).empty().append( content );` by any chance replace all the content including your "remove" button? If so, then the new button rendered by that command won't be bound to the event handler. Either change your code so it doesn't replace HTML which doesn't need replacing, or use delegated events to set the event handler on an element higher up the DOM which never gets removed, and which is a common ancestor of all your "remove" buttons. See http://api.jquery.com/on/ in the section "direct and delegated events", and all the dozens of previous SO questions on this exact topic.

Comment: oh and you never define "event", so preventDefault will never work in any situation. `tpj('.remove').on('click', function(event) {` would solve that

Comment: Yes my remove button is inside that replaced element @ADyson

Comment: @ADyson Ok so I removed all elements that don't need to be replaced. And made my onclick like this: `tpj('.cart_list .remove').on('click', function(event) {` `.cart_list` is never replaced, but still the same issue. What can I do?

Comment: is the .remove element being deleted and replaced by your ajax call now, or not? If it's not, then that should be fine (assuming .cart_list is a parent of .remove), but if it is, then it won't work - that's not the syntax for delegated events. Study the documentation again. Here's a clue: `tpj('.cart_list').on('click' '.remove', function(event) {`

Answer (score 0):

function(EVENT) foggoten in

```html
    tpj('.remove').on('click', function() {
    //...
    } 
must be:
    tpj('.remove').on('click', function(event) {
    //...
    }
```

Comment: Even if I add the `event` I still have the same issue, on the second click it redirects to my homepage.

Comment: event is not a requirement